# CSS3 transition not working in android emulator

Tags: android, css

I have defined a css3 transition [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2BWm8/54/). It is working well in mobile browser simulator, but not working in android emulator. I have tried adding the following codes also, but still not working.

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

any idea.

Comment: Why you don't declare a `rotate` and then start the animation?

Comment: Using rotate class only i am animating the div.

Comment: Wha tdo you mean with `div`, what do you want to rotate?